# Javascript - Multiple external files

Tags: javascript

I have a page which receives data from multiple sources and I need to create a set of handlers files to configure and display the different kinds of data. There could be 10-15 different kinds of data, each with it's own display logic. Each handler would be fairly large and not just 1 or two methods.

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way deliver an application like this, the only two options I can see are:

> 1) Create an individual handler file
>   for each type of data and externally load it in
>   when the page loads. The problem with
>   this is obviously including 10-15
>   different javascript files probably
>   isn't a smart idea. Would I need to compress all the handlers into one file, minify it and deliver it compressed?

or

> 2) Do all the configurations on the
>   server before pushing the data to the
>   user. Here the problem is that the
>   JSON data pushed back could be very
>   large (plus would include HTML) and put a lot of
>   strain on the server.

Can anyone shed any light on how best to deliver complex javascript apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I prefer your first option.

Combine and minify these JavaScript source files into a single one and cache it let Web browsers cache them in the client, meaning that subsequent requests wouldn't need to download this combined-and-minified large file, boosting Web site's performance and reducing network traffic.